# iAd does only once appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fullscreen, iad

I already despair all day on the following problem, I want to call a function displays advertisements, unfortunately it does this only in the second Calling. (On the first call, nothing happens and after the second call also does nothing more)

here the function:

```
- (void)showAd {
    self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyAutomatic;
    [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
    }
```

thx